# What is the proper method to export & reference a function within a user-defined class using the Ionic/Angular CLI version 5.4.16?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just started coding a week ago, and I am trying to make 2 buttons appear in my Ionic app (I am using Ionic CLI version 5.4.16), with the first being an action sheet button, and the second being an alert button. I am copying code from the official ionic documentation, but I am running into an issue when I try to export and then reference a function within my AlertClass (located in my home.page.ts file) in my home.page.html. I get the following error:

```
Identifier 'presentAlert' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Here is my home.page.html button code:

```
<ion-button (click)="presentActionSheet()" >Action Sheet</ion-button>

<ion-button (click)="presentAlert()">Alert</ion-button>
```

Here is my home.page.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionSheetController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {

  constructor(public actionSheetController: ActionSheetController) {}

  async presentActionSheet() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Albums',
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Delete',
        role: 'destructive',
        icon: 'trash',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Delete clicked');

        }
      }, {
        text: 'Share',
        icon: 'share',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Share clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Play (open modal)',
        icon: 'caret-forward-circle',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Play clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Favorite',
        icon: 'heart',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Favorite clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        icon: 'close',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'alert-example',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class AlertClass {
  constructor(public alertController: AlertController) {}

  async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      header: 'Alert',
      subHeader: 'Subtitle',
      message: 'This is an alert message.',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();
}
}
```

And here is my home.module.ts code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { AlertClass } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule, 
    
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
    AlertClass
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you want to present an alert when a click on the 'Alert' `ion-button` occurs. You are using Angular's event binding for that, as you should. As stated in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding) the quoted template statment, the `presentAlert()` in this case should be found on that component.

However, from what I see your function `presentAlert()` is defined in the exported class `AlertClass` instead. So what you want to do is move the `presentAlert()` to the `HomePage` class, alongside `presentActionSheet()`.

If you want to modularize the alert function, I suggest looking into services, cause it looks like what you intended to do with the `AlertClass`.

**tldr**: move the `presentAlert()` to the `HomePage` class, alongside `presentActionSheet()`.

Comment: Ah thank you. I will try this approach. What I ended up doing is making services with one class per service, and in each service I placed my functions. Then I made a function referring to each of my services in my home.page.ts file. Then in my home.page.html file, I referred each button to a particular function in my home.page.ts. This approach is overly complex, so I will try to implement your approach in the first chance I can. Once again, thank you for your response!

Comment: Haha yh, it is a bit complex, but it's really helpful to avoid repeating the same code, and it's how I manage my alerts too. If you wish, once you add the service class to the constructor, you can call the service's function in the html like: (click)="this.serviceClass.functionInService()".

Comment: Oh, for sure! Thanks! :)